# Check if date is within the timeframe and highlight the cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a set of dates and a `Gridview`. I'd like to check each date in the set of dates against the column title of the `Gridview`. If it's within the timeframe, I will highlight the column. Can it be done?

> An illustration

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|       |  07/11/2016 - 10/11/2016 | 11/11/2016 - 14/11/2016 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|       |                          |                         |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

So if I have a set of dates

```
09/11/2016, 13/11/2016
```

The **second cell** and **third cell** will be **highlighted** because `09/11/2016` is within the first timeframe and `13/11/2016` is within the second timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void grdListRelation_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ((DataGridView)sender).Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                   var celldata= cell.Value;
                   string[] dates=celldata.Split('-');
                   DateTime startDate== Convert.ToDateTime(dates[0]);  
                   DateTime endDate== Convert.ToDateTime(dates[1]);  
                   if(dateToCheck >= startDate && dateToCheck < endDate)
                   {
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                   } 
                 }
            }
        }
```

above code helps you to make it working.Give Vote if it work.